# R: Subsetting rows based on vector

Tags: r, dataframe, match, subset

Say I have a data frame like the following

```
A    B
PHX  5
DEN  3
DAL  1
HOU  2

df = data.frame(A = c("PHX", "DEN", "DAL", "HOU"), 
                B = c(5, 3, 1, 2))
```

Then I have a vector like the following

```
sel = c("PHX", "DAL", "PHX", "PHX")
```

I then wish to subset *df* to get the values of B after subsetting with `sel`. My result should be a vector like this:

```
res = c(5, 1, 5, 5)
```

What operation should I use to do this as subsetting with *==* wont work for vectors.

I could use `dplyr` or `vanilla R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `match` in base R:

```
with(df, B[match(sel, A)])

#[1] 5 1 5 5
```

Comment: @dandroid: I want to point out that duplicate values will not be reported with `match(sel, A)`. For instance, with the `df = data.frame(A = c("PHX", "DEN", "DAL", "HOU", "PHX"), B = c(5, 3, 1, 2, 6))`, you will still get `5 1 5 5` rather than `5 1 5 5 6`. This is an advantage of `joins`, which I think is provided as an example in the duplicate post.